# Как записать данные из html в MySQL?

Tags: база-данных, html, php, javascript, mysql

Есть структура `html` такого вида

```
<p>3.5 "Движение мотоциклов запрещено".</p>
<p>3.6 "Движение тракторов запрещено". Запрещается движение тракторов и самоходных машин.</p>
<p>3.7 "Движение пешеходов запрещено".</p>
```

То есть правила дорожного движения. Можно это как то автоматически вбить в базу данных MySQL,и задать каждому id начиная с 1 и до ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$content = '<p>3.5 "Движение мотоциклов запрещено".</p> <p>3.6 "Движение тракторов запрещено". Запрещается движение тракторов и самоходных машин.</p> <p>3.7 "Движение пешеходов запрещено".</p>';
preg_match_all('/"(?P<rules>[\w\s-]+)"/u', $content, $matches);

var_dump($matches['rules']);
```

или [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a0e2f73987a60b976c3b88b339e2e808dfbafd6d)

В правилах могут использоваться буквенно-цифровые символы, а также `_` и `-`.

Если в правилах используются иные символы, то я поправлю regexp-паттерн.

---

**UPDATE:**

Запросы будут выглядеть как-то так:

Создаём таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE `rules`(  
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Добавляем все записи одним запросом:

```
INSERT INTO `rules` (`name`) VALUES('Движение тракторов запрещено'),('Движение тракторов запрещено'),...;
```

**Теперь, как правильно ([почитайте "Почему стоит пользоваться PDO"](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/))**:

```
$dbname = 'pdd';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$table = 'rules';

try {
    //** Соединение с СУБД **//

    $pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8;", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //** Создание таблицы **//

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE `{$table}`(  
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` TEXT,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;";

    $pdo->exec($sql);

    //** Добавление записей в таблицу **//

    // Этот способ не универсальный, ибо подразумевает добавление значений только к одному полю "name". Если требуется для нескольких полей, то [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2098689), либо посмотрите в сторону ORM/DBAL.

    $values = array_fill(0, count($matches['rules']), '(?)');
    $values = implode(',', $values);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` (`name`) VALUES {$values}";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($matches['rules']);

} catch(\PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); // display error
}
```

Comment: Ну и добавить 
foreach ($matches['rules'] as $p){

..."Insert into table (field) values ($p)";

}

Comment: спасибо,я новичок в этом,а куда вот это все записывать?

Comment: 1. Создать таблицу БД с полем id (AUTO_INCREMENT) http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/example-AUTO_INCREMENT.html

2. В вышеприведенном цикле добавить в таблицу записи, не указывая поле id (поле будет определяться автоматически как авто-инкремент) 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: @Руслан Сабанов Дополнил ответ